# performSelector enters method on all instances, but only one thread finishes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, multithreading, objective-c-blocks

This may be a naive question, but I'll ask it anyway as I cannot find any documentation that clears up this issue in my head.

I'm running iOS5.1 both on device and in the simulator with Xcode45-DP4.

I have a loop that iterates over an array of a number of instances of a class. In that loop I use performSelector on the instances to start a thread that does some relatively slow network operations — pulling down data that I'd rather do in the background.

```
    [arrayOfFriends enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        Friend *f = (Friend*)obj;
        iOSSLog(@"%d", idx);
        [f performSelectorInBackground:@selector(showDescription) withObject:nil];



-(void)fetchTwitterStatus
{
iOSSLog(@"Trying to fetch twitterstatus %@ %@", self.hash, self.twitterUserName);
[mLocalTwitterUser fetchTwitterAPIUserStatusWithScreenName:twitterUserName
                                     withCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *arrayOfStatus, NSError *error) {
                                         if(error) {
                                             iOSSLog(@"%@", error);
                                         } else {
                                             iOSSLog(@"Got twitterstatus %@ %d", self.twitterUserName, [arrayOfStatus count]);
                                             @synchronized(items) {
                                                 [items addObjectsFromArray:arrayOfStatus];
                                             }
                                         }
                                     }];
}
```

In my test case there are four instances. Each instance gets its selector, you know..selected. The first three definitely start but only the last actually completes as indicated by the log line that says "Got twitterstatus..." Which is weird.

I can also verify that the method the selector calls "fetchTwitterStatus"

What is the little fundamental nugget of multithreading that I'm missing here?

EDIT: here's fetchTwitterAPIUserStatusWithScreenName...quite a bit here, but effectively it's calling the Twitter API Endpoint user_timeline with a JSON response.

```
- (void)fetchTwitterUserStatusWithScreenName:(NSString *)screenname
                          excludeReplies:(BOOL)excludeReplies
                   withCompletionHandler:(OtterTwitterSearchHandler)completionHandler

{
self.twitterAPIStatusHandler = completionHandler;
//self.fetchTwitterUserStatusHandler = completionHandler;
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=%@&include_rts=true&include_entities=true&exclude_replies=%@&count=50", screenname, excludeReplies?@"true":@"false"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

#warning this isn't the way to do it - just checking the cache for refresh of the scroller
[[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]removeCachedDataForURL:url];

iOSSRequest *request = [[iOSSRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                             parameters:nil
                                          requestMethod:iOSSRequestMethodGET];

NSMutableDictionary *oauthParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[oauthParams setObject:[[Twitter sharedService] apiKey] forKey:kASIOAuthConsumerKey];
[oauthParams setObject:[[Twitter sharedService] apiSecret] forKey:kASIOAuthConsumerSecret];
[oauthParams setObject:[self oAuthAccessToken] forKey:kASIOAuthTokenKey];
[oauthParams setObject:kASIOAuthSignatureMethodHMAC_SHA1 forKey:kASIOAuthSignatureMethodKey];
[oauthParams setObject:@"1.0" forKey:kASIOAuthVersionKey];
[oauthParams setObject:[self oAuthAccessTokenSecret] forKey:kASIOAuthTokenSecretKey];

request.oauth_params = oauthParams;


[request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        if (self.twitterAPIStatusHandler) {
            self.twitterAPIStatusHandler(nil, error);
            self.twitterAPIStatusHandler = nil;
        }
    } else {
        NSMutableArray *recentStatusForTwitterUser = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSArray *array = [Twitter JSONFromData:responseData];
        [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            TwitterStatus *twitterStatus = nil;
            twitterStatus = [[TwitterStatus alloc]initWithDictionary:obj];
            [recentStatusForTwitterUser addObject:twitterStatus];
        }];
        if (self.twitterAPIStatusHandler) {
            self.twitterAPIStatusHandler(recentStatusForTwitterUser, nil);
            self.twitterAPIStatusHandler = nil;
        }
    }
}];

}
```

Comment: What does the implementation of `fetchTwitterAPIUserStatusWithScreenName:withCompletionHandler:` look like? It looks that that could be the culprit.

Comment: You are using DP4, as that is prereleased software, any results or false results are irrelevant and subject to change once that software is released. Step 1, try to replicate your issues using released software.

Comment: Good suggestion @Till — tried it in Xcode4.4 and iOS5.1 and had the same results. There's something I'm not understanding here — that a thread'll go off and start something and then inexplicably vaporize if it isn't done the next time performSelector is called using a different instance of the target class. These aren't class methods, so I'm a bit baffled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using the asynchronous abstractions already provided where possible. It would be a fairly rare/unique situation where you need to deal with threads directly.

I've found treating each network-based background task as a synchronous `NSOperation` on a queue works really well.

Get a new instance of `NSOperationQueue`, configure it, add tasks to it, and manage the queue. The benefit of this approach is that each task can be implemented as a simple synchronous task, and the queue takes care of concurrency. Optionally you can set dependencies (this task must complete before that one).

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm going to see what NSOperationQUeue will do. Also I suppose I'm looking for the preferred idiom — and haven't tried operation queues at all. Perhaps this will give me some insight into why this is happening.

Comment: The encouragement from @ohhorob to look at NSOperation and NSOperationQueue led me on the right path, which is an embarrassing & educational one. 

I am using (and had forgotten) a singleton service class (which contains that fetch method above) that has all the oauth params I need to make authenticated requests. Thus I am doing bad re-entrant things. Last thread in gets its completion handler called. Bad Me. Sorry for the false alarm. I learned how to use NSOperation — so there's that. (Setting the max concurrency to 1 makes it all work properly, which isn't optimal, but..#shrug for now.)

Answer (score 0):

> What is the little fundamental nugget of multithreading that I'm
>   missing here?

That taking non-multithreaded code and spinning off a random number of threads by performing an arbitrary method in the background is doomed to failure.

Concurrency is a design pattern that must be carefully considered from the start (or is a monumental refactoring effort).

First, you don't want to spawn a thread per network connection.   Secondly, given that these are just HTTP requests, you would want to use the systems built in classes for asynchronous HTTP communications.  Finally, your concurrency model must exactly specify how you are keeping all data in isolation until you hit whatever mechanism you are using to synchronize the data back into the central store.

Hard to say where that code is going off the rails without seeing more information.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the complexity and care that goes into this. I don't expect I understand everything going on, but at least for the "fetch" code, it's sitting on top of ASIHTTPRequest, which I've found more than suitable in recent projects as a frame around built-in asynchronous HTTP classes & patterns. In the meantime, as well as taking your point, I may just decant the core bit of functionality out of this into a trivial project in order to understand why this issue happens — which is ultimately what I want to understand.